# Django Haystack exact Query not behaving as expected

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I am using django haystack's Exact match (with Whoosh) to filter and getting unexpected results.

**search_index.py**

```
class AssetIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)        
    asset_type = indexes.CharField(model_attr='asset_type')        
    brand = indexes.CharField(model_attr='brand')

    def prepare_brand(self, obj):
          return obj.brand.name

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
          """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
          return self.get_model().objects.filter(created_on__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

**views.py**

```
    assets = SearchQuerySet().models(Asset)
    assets = assets.filter(
                    content=query, asset_type=Exact('brand_asset'))
    assets = assets.filter(brand=Exact(b.name))
```

I expect the above to search like this: search by `query` and where the `asset_type` is equal to `brand_asset` and the `brand` is `b.name`. So everything is AND'd together.

In reality `brand` is not exact.  If I choose for example, Kraft or Kraft Mac n Cheese, I get the same results, even though these are two different brands.

TLDR - my search is not being limited to the `brand` field in my search index file.

## UPDATE

I get the same results with Elasticsearch too.